# Docker install tools/run command on existing container

Tags: apt, docker

I'm using Dokku to run some apps on an Ubuntu 14.04 server. Dokku creates the Docker container with all the stuff in them to run.

I'd like to connect to the running container somehow and run `apt-get install phantomjs -y`.

How would I go about doing this? If I run this on the Ubuntu host machine will it be available in the docker container?

I don't have access to the Docker file or the buildpacks since that's all part of Dokku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to your application container run

```
dokku run <app-name> bash
```

Then

```
apt-get update
apt-get install <package>
```

P.S. Another way to do so:

```
docker ps
docker attach --sig-proxy=false <your-app-container>
```

This may also not work depending on Dokku configuration.

**Edit:**
Actually, the best way to do it, is to use [dokku-apt](https://github.com/F4-Group/dokku-apt) plugin.

Comment: Thank you so much for this it does work! I'm stuck on having the changes persist. E.g if I install phantomjs and exit, then dokku run bash again its not there anymore is there something more that has to be done?

Comment: Yeah, Dokku will reset changes to container. So the best way is to use either dokku-apt or pass docker param via [dokku-docker-options](https://github.com/dyson/dokku-docker-options). When using dokku-apt simply specify required modules in `apt-packages` file and save it in your project's root.

Comment: how to do it in a non interactive way? e.g from travis for example